# How does `sizeof` distinguish a pointer from an array?

Tags: c, sizeof

Note that if `a` is an array name, then `sizeof(a)` will yields the size of the entire array `a` and not the size of a pointer to one of its elements.

So for example, how does `sizeof` distinguish an array `a` and a pointer `b`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  int *b = a;
  printf("sizeof\(a) = %ld\n", sizeof(a));
  printf("sizeof\(b) = %ld\n", sizeof(b));
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It prints as below:

```
sizeof(a) = 16
sizeof(b) = 8
```

Comment: Well, it's known at compile time what is an array and what is not, and since `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time too, it's not difficult to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Comment: Compare what happens if you put the `printf` calls in a separate function and pass `a` and `b` as pointers, and you'll get a clear idea of how it works.

Comment: The compiler does that, **not** the `sizeof` operator. How does it do it? Well, how do you do it? A simple glance is enough, right? It just as easy for the compiler (or whoever implements it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`sizeof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) is a *compile-time* operator. It is computed by the compiler (and is almost always a constant, [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s being the exception).

The compiler is obviously knowing when a variable refers to an array or to a pointer because it has to know the type of every variable (and an array type is not the same as a pointer type).

Notice that in C an array can [decay](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) into a pointer (e.g. when you pass an array as an argument to a routine). This is one of the most tricky points of the C language (so dive into a C programming book if you don't understand it).

Answer (score 1):

the compiler keeps an eye on every name(array, integer, pointer, ....) you define in your code, it's address and it's size and save it in a table along with other inforamtion . so when you use the `sizeof` operator the compiler just replaces the expression with the size of that name and compile your program with a hard-coded number that is: the size of the operand, and that is why you can't use `sizeof` with dynamically sized structures at run time.
So, in your example the compiler has a table like

name____address____size_____....(other things)

a_____1000_____16_____....(the array)  <<<

b_____1016_____8_____.....

.._____1024_____.._____.......

and when you use an expression like

```
printf("sizeof\(a) = %ld\n", sizeof(a));
```

the compiler will replace it (at one of the translation phases) with

```
printf("sizeof\(a) = %ld\n", 16);
```

and then continue it's compilation work